# merging two dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge

I have data  in a dataframe with 139104 rows which is multiple of 96x1449. i have a phenotype file which contains the phenotype information for the 96 samples. the snp name is repeated 1449X96 samples. I haveto merge the two dataframes based on sid and sen. this is how my two dataframes look like

```
dat <- data.frame(
    snpname=rep(letters[1:12],12),
    sid=rep(1:12,each=12), 
    genotype=rep(c('aa','ab','bb'), 12)
)
pheno <- data.frame(
    sen=1:12,
    disease=rep(c('N','Y'),6), 
    wellid=1:12
)
```

I have to merge or add the disease column and 3 other columns to the data file. I am unable to use merge in R. I have searched google, i am not hitting the correct terms to get the answer. I would appreciate any input on this issue.

Thanks, Sharad

Comment: `dat <- merge(dat, pheno, by.x = "sid", by.y = "sen", all=TRUE)`

Comment: For latter use, don't miss the [snpMatrix](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.3/bioc/html/snpMatrix.html) (efficient storage of genotype data, fast GLMs), [snpAssoc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SNPassoc/index.html) (user-friendly), or [GenABEL](http://www.genabel.org/) packages. Most allow to build specific structure (or environment, with [GGtools](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.2/bioc/html/GGtools.html)) for manipulating and merging genotype and phenotype data.

Comment: @Ista, next time post as an answer. That way, you can be rewarded in a little way.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the columns you want to match on directly with `merge()`:

```
merge(dat, pheno, by.x = "sid", by.y = "sen")
```